# C# - RaisePropertyChanged called multiple times and throwing stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm fairly new to WPF. I have the following radio button in my application

```
<Viewbox Height="30">
     <RadioButton Content="B1" GroupName="InputBelt" IsChecked="{Binding RBChecked, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Viewbox>
<Viewbox Height="30">
     <RadioButton Content="B2" GroupName="InputBelt" IsChecked="{Binding RBChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolconverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Viewbox>
```

I have defined datacontext in xaml file

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:TestViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

The issue is when the page is loaded for the 1st time, everything is fine. But when I go to some other page in the application and comes back to this page, the application crashes due to stackoverflow exception.

I even tried adding datacontext locally in radiobutton tag but it isn't working either.

Property structure given below.

```
private bool _bRBChecked;
public bool RBChecked
{
    get { return _bRBChecked; }
    set
    {
        _bRBChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RBChecked");
    }
}
```

Upon investigating further, I found out that the RaisePropertyChanged of the binded property is being called too many times. This issue occurs only with the property binded to radio button. I have other controls which has two-way bind with other properties in the same page and it seems to work fine.

Now I have tried the below fix suggested in another stackoverflow question and it seems to be working.

```
set
{
    if (_bRBChecked != value)
    {
        _bRBChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RBChecked");
    }
}
```

But I would like to know the root cause of this issue and why the property is being set so many times and find any alternate fix if possible. Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Any insight is highly appreciable.

Comment: It seems odd that you have two radiobuttons at all when they're both bound to the same property. If you just removed the second binding. Wouldn't that do what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your change notification is not protected from recursion. Property A changing Property B, whose change changes Property A...

A simple solution is this:

```
set
{
    if(value != _bRBChecked){
      _bRBChecked = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("RBChecked");
    }
}
```

Simply check if the value is actually a change, before you go tell everyone about it. This pattern is explicitly used in the [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged). I am 90% sure the Depdency Properties have a similar recursion protection, but it would not be the first time I was wrong.

Comment: I have used this and it is working. But I would like to know what causes the recursion. Even after using this, I see the raisedpropertychanged function being called 4-6 times for this property. It sets false once and again it sets true it goes on till it sets the correct/fallback value.

Comment: @coder_g Binding is (usually) a two way street. **Both** sides have Change Notification, in one Flavor or another. So you write their value, wich writes your value, wich writes their value...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fairly easy to figure this out, based on the fix you shared.

What happens in steps:

1. You set the new value in one of the radio buttons
2. The event is raised
3. Since it's two way binding, the binding of the second radio button sets the value again to the other radio button
4. The event is raised again due to 3
5. Go back to 1 as now the value is set again for the first radio button.

With your fix the value is not set (the setter it's not called) so the event is not triggered again.

Comment: Oh now I seem to get why it causes a recursive call. Thanks for the explanation @Athanasios. So it looks like checking the value before setting it in property is the only solution?

Comment: Indeed it is! Nothing more to do,  except create a different binding per control which does not make sense.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks @Athanasios